# Google APIs to get app revenue of all apps

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-client

I'm trying to get app revenue through Google Play purchases of Android apps from a Google API.
The aim is to display a list of all apps with their revenue, the sum of all together and, if possible, to drill down to see the revenue per country.

I saw that this can be done with [Google Analytics Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1). The problem is that I need to add the property ID of the apps as a path parameter. But there is no method to get a list of all properties.
I already searched other APIs to find a way to do so.

- [Google Play Android Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest), doesn't offer a list of apps
  or property IDs neither. It anyway does not serve a method to see the overall revenue of an app
- [Google Analytics Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/?apix=true) only
  queries for existing reports, which is not appropriate, because I
  don't want to force a user to create report in Google Analytics, nor
  do I want to be dependent on a static report.
- [Google Analytics Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/?apix=true) offers a way to query web properties. But apps are not in the list, because they are no **web** properties.

I'm pretty sure there is a way to do so, because the [Google Play Console App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.playconsole) displays the revenue per app and I assume their using a public API as well.

**Solution:**

As stated in a comment in the answer of Brett, the [Google Analytics Admin API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1alpha/properties/list) might be used to get a list of all accounts and their respective properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Google Analytics Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1) reports on a single GA4 property with each API request. However, a single GA4 property can have several data streams, and you can add one data stream for each app. This [article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9304153) describes adding data streams to a GA4 property.

Comment: Actually it's not a problem to execute one request for each property and to aggregate them. But I still don't know how to get the properties of an account through APIs?
Btw. I don't care, whether I get the data through Analytics or another API.

Comment: The [accountSummaries.list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1alpha/accountSummaries/list) will list all the GA4 accounts and properties that you have access to. For example, the response will contain
```
{
"property": "properties/1234",
"displayName": "My Ga4 Property Display Name"
}
```
This property ID (1234) can be passed to the GA4 Data API. Alternatively, the [properties.list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1alpha/properties/list) method can return all GA4 properties for a single account.

Comment: Thanks Brett, that's exactly what I was looking for.
Do you know, whether I have to enable the Google Analytics Admin API in the cloud console? Because I cannot find it there (only Data API, Management API and Reporting API are listed).

Comment: The Admin API is present in the Cloud Console. Try typing "Google Analytics Admin API" into the Cloud Console's search box at the top-middle of any page. If you don't enable the Admin API for a project, all API requests to the Admin API will fail; the error message will contain a link to the cloud console to enable the Admin API.